# How big web application can be developed by Spring Roo?

Tags: spring-roo

Going to develop a web application, may be there will be more than 100 tables & 3 developers may need one years to complete the project. 
Thinking to use Spring Roo+ Spring Security + Oracle DB for developing this project. We are all new in Spring Roo but we have Spring MVC development knowledge.

Is this our right technology selection? Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!
Rafiq

Answer (score 1):

In our company we are working in projects like that, some in Production stage.

You must think Spring Roo as a tool which can help you to start your project but, finally, you'll get a (almost) standard Spring project. What you can do with Spring is suitable for a Roo generated project. More over, if you wish you can remove all Spring Roo assets from your project and it continue working.

In addition, there are some useful tools:

- [gvNIX](http://www.gvnix.org/en/index.html): Spring Roo add-on suite which includes some useful tools (JQuery, Datatables, auditing, Reports)
- [liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org/): Tool to handle DB changes. Useful to generate SQL to handle Physical model changes.
- [QueryDSL](http://www.querydsl.com/): Useful to generate complex queries, much more simple than JPA Criteria definition

Good luck!